# $\int d^3\vec{r}_1\int d^3\vec{r}_2e^{-\frac{\beta K}{2}|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|^2}=V\int d^3\vec{r}e^{-\frac{\beta K}{2}|\vec{r}|^2}$

Tags: integration

I was reading the solution of a problem when I saw this:

> $$\int d^3\vec{r}_1\int d^3\vec{r}_2e^\left(-\frac{\beta K}{2}|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|^2\right)=V\int d^3\vec{r}e^\left(-\frac{\beta K}{2}|\vec{r}|^2\right)$$
> where $$\int d^3\vec{r}_n=V\;\;\forall\;\;n$$
> $\beta, K \longrightarrow$ constants

Just to give you a bit of the context, there is a step of the solution of a statistical physics problem on canonical ensemble where the solver assumpted this.

Comment: Awful title choice. Please make the title more specific to the question.

Comment: @AdamRubinson so I put the whole integral in the title as I didn't know how to describe the problem properly

Comment: Have you tried a change of variables?

Comment: This is just a rotation by letting $r'=r_1+r_2$ and $r= r_1-r_2$ (or some scalar multiple thereof) but you may want to check that the integral isn't missing a constant somewhere. As written, the unscaled summations do not have Jacobian 1